# formatting output of code into table format

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, average

I have the following code here that manages to web scrape information of the website, but I wish to run this code every 10 seconds to refresh running this code as well as formatting the output of this code into a nice table with the average of the top 5 values. How should I go around doing this?

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://otc-api-hk.eiijo.cn/v1/data/trade-market?coinId=2&currency=3&tradeType=sell&blockType=general'
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
print('USDT SGD')
print('----')
for d in data['data']:
    print('{:<30}{}'.format(d['userName'], d['price']))
    
url = 'https://otc-api.hbg.com/v1/data/trade-market?coinId=1&currency=3&tradeType=sell&blockType=general'
data = requests.get(url).json()

print('BTC SGD')
print('----')
for d in data['data']:
    print('{:<30}{}'.format(d['userName'], d['price']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it into a pandas data frame, calculate the average using nlargest, print the data and the average

```
df = pd.Dataframe(data['data'])
df = df[['userName','price']]
top_5_avg = df.nlargest(5, "price")['price].mean()
print(df)
print(f'The average of top 5 is {top_5_avg}')
```

Comment: When I run df = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(data['data'], columns = ['username', 'price'], orient = "index"),  I get the following error:  'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I did not realize it was a list of dictionaries. The edited code should work